# Disable Windows Magnifier on Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I am using a magnifier on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am using Auto Hotkey to send <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>  and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> by mouse wheel and keyboard combo.

The problem is when I send <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> with Auto hotkey it opens up another windows magnifier on remote machine to which I have taken RDP because <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> happens to be windows shorcut keys to open up windows magnifier. Opening up magnifier on Remote machine makes it lag like hell.

How can I switch off magnifier on remote machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirement is turning off the hotkey of the windows magnifier. please refer to the following steps.

1. open the file explorer
2. find the program: `C:\Windows\System32\Magnify.exe`
3. Then right-click it and change the `ownership`, and change the permissions to be `full control`, you can just use the administrator to take ownership.
4. Then rename the `Magnify.exe` file as other name.

Or just change permissions of the windows magnify(Magnify.exe) that can't be read.

[image]

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I can't do that as there are lot of servers and client won't give me admin access. Right now the only way I found is: disable control keys input to the remote client in Remote Desktop Manager. Atleast the clipboard still works and I can manage without sending other keyboard combos to the remote client.